# What sealant to use on a hole in the interior of the house on an external wall?

Tags: tile, baseboard, sealant

There's a tiny, tiny hole in an external wall that separates my living room and the outside front entryway.  This is important because I just saw a bug crawl through the hole from the outside into my home.

Actually, to describe the hole more accurately, the baseboard goes along the wall on top of my carpet.  Where it transitions from carpet to the tile for the front entryway I can see some sealant, since the baseboard is 1/4 inch off the ground b/c of the carpet.  There's a tiny hole where it transitions from the carpet to the tile.

What kind of sealant should I use to spray into the hole to fill it up and prevent bugs from entering?  Should I spray from the outside if I can find a corresponding hole outside or from the inside where I can clearly see the hole?

EDIT: Here's a photo of the hole[image: hole]

Comment: I would like to see the hole. In general, you're going to get better responses on DIY if you have a picture.

Comment: @Machavity, I've attached a photo of the hole, although, one of the answers said I should do it from the outside.  However, I don't see a hole on the outside of the wall so...

Answer (score 3):

Attempting to seal this from the inside probably won't work. If insects are getting through, there must be a gap in the exterior sheathing or framing. Closing off that one gap under the trim won't solve the problem as the insects will find another route, such as through the carpet.

Find the opening on the outside and either repair the problem in the structure or use a combination of exterior caulk and spray foam, as needed.

You might also treat the area outside the building with an insecticide.

Comment: Yes it needs to be sealed from the outside, exterior latter calking is what you need+